# How do I prepare a CRA app to deploy to heroku, do I still have to build as for a fullstack CRA app?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a simple create-react-app app that I want to deploy to heroku but I'm not sure about the right wat to deplay or what files exactly. Do I need to `npm run build` as in the case of a mern fullstack app? I repeat, this is only react, no server. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Heroku to deploy just the React part, no server, you can use other easier solutions like:
[Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) and [Vercel](https://vercel.com/).

What you need need to do that, is just have a GitHub/GitLab repository, register on the platform, choose your repository and wait :)

It will automatically build and serve your React application.

Another cool thing is: Any new commit will generate a new build, so your app will be always updated.

Comment: All this sounds great, but how do I see my deployed app? Where do I go> Will I find it in my Netlify account as a link or something?

Comment: OMG mate. You helped me a great deal, I now have a live website on Netlify. After struggling with Heroku errors, you came into my life and suggested I use Netlify. Simply amazing stuff. I even bought a custom domain name. :)) Thanks.

Comment: Cooool! Netlify is awesome! I'm glad that I helped you!